# remote performance measurement in windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, performancecounter

I'm doing some perfomance logging on a windows 7 based target system, with two administrator accounts (ADMIN1 and ADMIN2).To do the ligging, I have a host PC (also windows 7) that connects to the target PC, which has one admin account (ADMIN1). I have made a c# program that runs on the host, that uses [Perfomance Counters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to sample the performance logging on the target pc, using the NextSample() function.

This works fine on the current setup because both systems use the same admin account (ADMIN1). However for reasons beyond my control ADMIN1 has to be deleted on the target system. Now, whenever I call NextSample() I get an error "Access denied".

My question is, how to fix this? I have some restrictions though.
First, if it is possible I don't want to change the OS settings on the target pc (so I cannot change the Performance Monitor Users and Performance Log Users groups) to keep the target system as "as-is" as possible.
Second I don't want to create a new user account on my host pc (so I don't want to create ADMIN2).

I'm not sure if it is even possible with these restriction, so please advise.

Comment: use xperf/WPR t capture perf data (CPU, disk) and transfer it to the 2nd PC and analyte it there with WPA: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it, using `runas`.

```
runas /netonly /user:remotedomain\ADMIN2 "myApp.exe"
```

This will start myApp and when using remote access to retreive the performance logging it uses the remote credentials (password is asked upon execution).